# How can I find all cells in Excel with a particular value and get the sum of all those cells' dependents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to find the total number of screws, nuts, washers, etc for a very large assembly. For each part in the assembly, I have the number of each type of hardware. I would like to find the total number of screws, etc.

For example, say in A1 I have "2018 Screw" and in B1 I have the number of 2018 screws.
Then in A2 I have "1505 Nut" and in B2, number of 1505 nuts.
And so on for many, many parts and many pieces of hardware.

I want to ask Excel to find all the cells containing "2018 Screw" and then add up all the cells that depend on those.

I'm not sure if I am explaining my question well or if someone else has asked a similar question. Please re-direct me if a similar question has already been answered.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data set up like so:

[image: Example Data]

Select the data and then select "Format as Table".

[image: Format as Table Menu]

Right click on the table and then select Table --> Totals Row.  You can play around with what types of functions for each column, but sum will give you the total within that column.  You can then filter based on entries using the down arrows next to the column titles:

[image: Table Filtering]

[image: Filtered Table]

Comment: How would I do this if 2018 screws are scattered throughout the spreadsheet?

Comment: @user231729 Once you create the table you can filter the entries (see expanded answer above).  Doesn't matter their location.